# How to make real time log for incoming/outgoing/missed calls on phone

Tags: android

How to make real time call log?

I want to create real time log for incoming/outgoing/missed calls in my phone but i am unable to do this as it seems impossible to have account of running calls.

I am getting last call in call history but not the running one.

Comment: I want this to implement on android phone..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I may have answered late.   But the answer is easily found via googling:

http://www.google.com/search?q=CallLog.Calls+android+%22missed+calls%22

Keywords is "CallLog.Calls" and those answer found in w